# PDFtron low level text extractore gly issue

Tags: python, pdf, pdfnet

Base problem: The PDFTron lib font.MapToUnicode return wrong case character.

Details: This is happens in particular book the snap are attached below, there are few character are getting in lower case but char.char_code is for upper case. as per my knowledge the font character and gly mapping having a problem. please go through the code and file and let me help in this case

[pdf_file_prob_char](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1woZv6vGH5Gub6uzwsCIC7Hf5iGQgiqJC/view?usp=sharing)

environment:
PDFNetPython3 lib vr : 9.4.2

Original PDF has some capital letters, but we get small letter as character
PDF text is capital 'O' but PDFTron text-extractor gives small 'o'

snap of pdf :

[image]

code :

```
from PDFNetPython3.PDFNetPython import PDFNet, PDFDoc, ElementReader, Element, Point
from PDFNetPython3.PDFNetPython import Font, GState, ColorSpace, PatternColor, PathData
```

class CharFromPDF:

```
def __init__(self):
    pass

def print_char_from_pdf(self, pdf_file_path):
    PDFNet.Initialize("demo:1691991990538:7c56930b030000000055aed6bf8e4eb6a00bb237070a3797ee21cafe95")
    doc = PDFDoc(pdf_file_path)
    doc.InitSecurityHandler()
    page_begin = doc.GetPageIterator()
    page_reader = ElementReader()

    itr = page_begin
    while itr.HasNext():
        page_reader.Begin(itr.Current())
        self.process_elements(page_reader)
        page_reader.End()
        itr.Next()
    doc.Close()
    PDFNet.Terminate()
    print("Done.")

def process_path(self, reader, path):
    gs = path.GetGState()
    gs_itr = reader.GetChangesIterator()
    while gs_itr.HasNext():
        if gs_itr.Current() == GState.e_fill_color:
            if (gs.GetFillColorSpace().GetType() == ColorSpace.e_pattern and
                    gs.GetFillPattern().GetType() != PatternColor.e_shading):
                reader.PatternBegin(True)
                self.process_elements(reader)
                reader.End()
        gs_itr.Next()
    reader.ClearChangeList()

def process_text(self, page_reader):
    # Begin text element
    element = page_reader.Next()
    while element is not None:
        element_type = element.GetType()
        if element_type == Element.e_text_end:
            return
        elif element_type == Element.e_text:
            gs = element.GetGState()
            font = gs.GetFont()
            if font.GetType() == Font.e_Type3:
                itr = element.GetCharIterator()
                while itr.HasNext():
                    page_reader.Type3FontBegin(itr.Current())
                    self.process_elements(page_reader)
                    page_reader.End()
            else:
                itr = element.GetCharIterator()
                while itr.HasNext():
                    char_code = itr.Current().char_code
                    a = font.MapToUnicode(char_code)
                    print("Char: ", a[0], " ascii code: ", ascii(a[0]), "char_code", char_code,
                          " Font Name: ", font.GetName())
                    itr.Next()
            print("")
        element = page_reader.Next()

def process_elements(self, reader):
    element = reader.Next()
    while element is not None:
        element_type = element.GetType()
        if element_type == Element.e_path:
            self.process_path(reader, element)
        elif element_type == Element.e_text_begin:
            self.process_text(reader)
        elif element_type == Element.e_form:
            reader.FormBegin()
            self.process_elements(reader)
            reader.End()
        element = reader.Next()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    cfp = CharFromPDF()
    input_file_path = "text_issue.pdf"
    cfp.print_char_from_pdf(pdf_file_path=input_file_path)
```

In above example you find the font.MaptoUnicode the character code for "o" is capital case but function return small case letter

we try the textextracter as well from same lib but the return vise versa out but as text.

Comment: The **ToUnicode** map of that font in your problem PDF has an error, it only has entries for single byte character codes (which is correct) but it claims to have a code space range from `0000` to `ffff`, i.e. of double byte character codes. This error may result in unexpected outputs by PDF text extractors.

Comment: ok, double byte chr code it menses pdf has substitute font? @mkl

Comment: It means that the **ToUnicode** map of that font is not valid for its use: *"The **CMap** file shall contain **begincodespacerange** and **endcodespacerange** operators that are consistent with the encoding that the font uses. In particular, for a simple font, the codespace shall be one byte long."* (ISO 32000-2, section 9.10.3) Your PDF file explicitly violates this requirement.

Comment: but the pdf readers are render that page perfectly, how they do that can you have any information about the same.

Comment: *"but the pdf readers are render that page perfectly, how they do that can you have any information about the same."* - To render glyphs, a viewer does not need to know which Unicode character they represent. Embedded fonts in PDFs often are subsets with a non-standard encoding (e.g. the first glyph they need on a page gets the code 1, the second one the code 2...). Using those codes on the page is all a PDF viewer needs to display the correct glyph. Text extraction, on the other hand, is optional in PDFs, so some PDF producers fail in providing the needed information, and then it's guesswork.

Answer (score 1):

The font used to display the text has a ToUnicode cmap that maps 'O' (upper case O) to 'o' (lower case o). 
PDF specification says that when extracting text from PDF, the ToUnicode cmap should be considered first and then the font's encoding.
It seems that Acrobat ignores the ToUnicode cmap in favor of the font's WinAnsi encoding. Even after fixing the cmap's code space range Acrobat still ignores it, so this might be Acrobat's particular behavior with WinAnsi encoding (not compliant with PDF specification).
Other PDF readers such as SumatraPDF use the ToUnicode cmap for text extraction so their output is the same as PDFTron.

Comment: In addition to the **ToUnicode** map the file also contains **ActualText** marked content properties which also constitute a mechanism for text extraction mentioned in the spec. Adobe Acrobat prefers **ActualText** data over **ToUnicode** mappings. Many other text extractors don't use **ActualText**. Thus, the behavior of Acrobat may still be compliant with the spec.

Comment: @mkl yes, probably Acrobat favors ActualText over the ToUnicode cmap.